# After selecting list of columns in pyspark will rest of unselected columns be hidden?

Tags: pyspark

[image]

In the above table i have 5 columns and selected 2 columns and saved as new dataframe. From unselected column when i try to retrieve information on new dataframe its returning result instead of trowing error as column not present in dataframe.

**Sample Code:**

```
df1 = df.select('id', 'subject1')
df1.filter('subject2' > 50).show()
```

Above dataframe dosen't have subject2 but its returning result instead of trowing error. How to completely drop list of columns from memory?

**Output dataframe result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pyspark is lazily evaluated whenever you apply .select or .drop they are not performed right there and is added to the DAG and will be selected later after an action is applied to the dataframe.

So, you can filter on the non-selected column also as long as there is no action applied to the dataframe.

For memory concern, spark doesn't reads anything in memory till the action is performed, it only creates the DAG and once you perform the action only then things start getting into the memory.

Comment: Better visit this blog for cache https://unraveldata.com/to-cache-or-not-to-cache/

Answer (score 0):

cannot reproduce your case. In general when you select some columns - only those will be available for filtering. You should get a type error that condition should be string or column. Please ensure that above in the code you didn't specify subject2 as an object.

Also try:

```
df1 = df1.drop('subject2', 'subject3', 'subject4')
```

Hope this helps.